# Node response is 0 bytes/empty

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, response

Just trying a basic hello world while coding a lingo game. I get a response header with a 200, my localhost node server outputs to the console that I've sent the response, yet the response is always empty. I tried to do this without express as well and it still comes back empty. The server-side code is below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
res.send("Hello");
console.log("Successful response");
});

app.listen(3001);
```

The client-side page is below:

```
</head>
<body>
<div id='header'>
<h2>Welcome to Lingo!</h2>
</div>
<div id='game area'>
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" value="" id="textfield"></input>
<div id="select_div"><a href="#" id="select_link">Test</a></div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#select_div').click(function(e){
$.get('http://localhost:3001',function(res){
alert("Worked");
});
});
});    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a lot of different things and googled different questions but none answer this. I don't understand how I can be getting a successful response header yet no response. And when I attempt to connect to localhost:3001 in the browser, the response text is there "Hello" on a page.

Comment: Where are you sending the request from when the response is "empty?" curl? wget? Something else?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I'm running a node.js server on localhost port 3001. I make a request to that same address from my index page, I can see in firebug that the request and response are good (status 200) but the response is empty.

Comment: I guess what you're saying is that your `$.get()` is what is receiving an empty response but visiting the url directly (not via XHR), you see the expected response?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The alert in the get callback never gets called.

Comment: Where is your HTML being served from? The same `localhost:3001` server or somewhere else (including locally via `file://`).

Comment: The same localhost:3001. Really, its not much of html, it is just the word "Hello" appended to the response stream. I am not sure if this is sufficient but all the demo apps I've seen have started this way...

Comment: The reason I asked is because I was curious if perhaps the XHR was a CORS request and it did not get a response because the browser did not see the appropriate response headers to allow the response to be made available to the XHR.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm not sure.

Comment: Could my antivirus/popup blocker or something like this be preventing the response?